# IlegalStateException where thrown, while trying to retrieve values from RoomDatabase instance

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I'm using android new architecture component **room** for database operations, I got in trouble, when I'm trying to retrieve objects from database

```
Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

this is my Dao interface

```
@Dao
interface BookDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM books")
    fun getAllBooks() : List<Book>

    @Insert
    fun saveBook(book: Book)

    @Query("DELETE FROM books")
    fun deleteBookTable()
}
```

that is my table model class

```
@Entity(tableName = "books")
data class Book(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "book_title")
        var title: String,
        var imgRes: Int,
        var filePath: String? = null,
        var pdfInBytes: ByteArray? = null,
        @PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
        var bookId: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
) : Serializable
```

and this is RoomDatabase child class

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Book::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun bookDao(): BookDao

    companion object {

         @Volatile private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

         fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase =
             INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
             INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(context).also { INSTANCE = it }
         }

         private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
             Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java, "booksDB.db")
                    .build()
    }
}
```

this is code bloke where I'm invoking this method

```
private val db: AppDatabase by lazy { AppDatabase.getInstance(this) }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    doAsync { // from anko library
       for (i in 0..10){
           val book = Book("$i", tmpImgRes, "tmpPath", tmpBytes)
           db.bookDao().saveBook(book)
       }
       val books = db.bookDao().getAllBooks()
   }
}
```

when I'm trying to call getAllBooks() exception where thrown.

room implementation:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-rc1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-rc1"
```

Comment: did you find the solutions @Jemo

Comment: yes,in my case the problem where the sizes in each sqlite db row, I was saving there more than 2.5MB bytes of array and than when I was trying to retrieve it the error were thrown

Comment: so whats the solution?

Comment: split bytes of data, for ex: I had 18MB of data to be stored in db and I sliced it for 1MB bytes of array, than when I wanted to read it selected it and merged, that's all

Comment: Can you please post your solution as Answer.it'll help others.

Comment: Ok, I have wrote the my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, the actual problem, where in SQLite table row sizes, when I was trying to fetch the data from the table, the row where contained more than 2.5 MB data and It is not fine in SQLite database, than I reduce the sizes of data by split the array of bytes and saved it by chunks, after that every thing worked perfectly, after fetching I merged it as it were original